# Microsoft Excel Query - Formatting Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have got an excel sheet data that looks like this:

[image]

```
Order Id    Rate    Item    Quantity
XXX          4      Ball      100
XXX          4      Hockey    500
XXX          4      Hockey    500
AAA          3      Ball      200
AAA          3      Ball      300
AAA          6      Helmet    800
AAA          6      Helmet    100
```

I need to get the Quantity Subtotaled under the same orderId and Rate and the different Items under the same order to be separated by comma under Item. Basically the output should look like this :

```
Order Id    Rate      Item     Quantity
XXX          4   Ball, Hockey   1100
AAA          3       Ball       500
AAA          6      Helmet      900
```

Output screenshot in excel -

[image]

Comment: Raystafarian's answer is pretty close and certainly the least painful. However, if you really need all the `item` data to be in a single cell, you're stuck with one of two options: 1) PivotTable with complicated formulas that get *really* messy if the number of `item`s changes OR 2) VBA. Which route is preferable?

Comment: I agree with @eng - this will require VBA

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [pivot table](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!

Select the range and go to ***Insert - Pivot Table***

For *row labels*, you can use `rate` and `order id`

For *column labels* you can use `item`

And you can sum the values of `qty`

[click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ESI3.png)

[image]

Comment: You can get a bit closer to the desired output by changing to classic layout and repeating item labels for `order id`

Comment: @EngineerToast Unfortunately I have 2007 on this computer, but this would definitely work for OP with 2010

Comment: @Rahul, remember if this post answers the question or is helpful, mark as answer (green tick) or upvote (or both)!

Comment: Hi Friends Can't use the pivot table. I have attached the result as reqd. The data I have posted in example is just an example. Actual data is huge and also the pivot creates different rows for the Items here so it would become a massive table. The result I need is similar to highlighted in screenshot -  ( http://screencast.com/t/0UJ7H9IAI7) - items separated by comma

Comment: I don't understand why it takes out http from front. It is(please ignore spaces in between) -  http : // screencast.com/t/0UJ7H9IAI7